# Using InsertOne/UpdateOne to add value in DB - If previous value found; returns NaN instead of actual number

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, discord.js

**Hello there!**

I am currently trying to wrap my head around having a "Rate 1-5 stars" function in my DiscordJS bot.

I've come to the point where i can add a value to OneStar (with the command seen below image)

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ln5vIWo.png]

It inputs as expected to OneStar, since its the first time the admin gets rated with 1 star.

But as soon as i try thereafter to add a value to another object, like TwoStar - they return out as NaN.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/np5swnk.png]

Now comes the funny part.
If i decide to add a value to TwoStar first (!rate admin @MENIX 2)

cause now the admin had a two star rating, it returns a value as expected - but then if i after add to OneStar; then that will now return NaN

[image]

**This is the full code for this bit:**

Functions.js:

```
AddRating: async function (UserID, toAdd) {
        const mclient = await MongoClient.connect(url, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
        if (!mclient) return;
        try {
            const db = await mclient.db("DV");
            let collection = db.collection("rating")
            var res = await collection.find({
                id: UserID
            }).toArray()
            if (toAdd === "1") {
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    await collection.insertOne({
                        id: UserID,
                        OneStar: parseInt(1)
                    })
                } else {
                    var myquery = {
                        id: UserID
                    };
                    var newvalues = {
                        $set: {
                            OneStar: parseInt(res[0].OneStar) + parseInt(1)
                        }
                    };

                    await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
                }
            }
            if (toAdd === "2") {
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    await collection.insertOne({
                        id: UserID,
                        TwoStar: parseInt(1)
                    })
                } else {
                    var myquery = {
                        id: UserID
                    };
                    var newvalues = {
                        $set: {
                            TwoStar: parseInt(res[0].TwoStar) + parseInt(1)
                        }
                    };

                    await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
                }
            }
            if (toAdd === "3") {
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    await collection.insertOne({
                        id: UserID,
                        ThreeStar: parseInt(1)
                    })
                } else {
                    var myquery = {
                        id: UserID
                    };
                    var newvalues = {
                        $set: {
                            ThreeStar: parseInt(res[0].ThreeStar) + parseInt(1)
                        }
                    };

                    await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
                }
            }
            if (toAdd === "4") {
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    await collection.insertOne({
                        id: UserID,
                        FourStar: parseInt(1)
                    })
                } else {
                    var myquery = {
                        id: UserID
                    };
                    var newvalues = {
                        $set: {
                            FourStar: parseInt(res[0].FourStar) + parseInt(1)
                        }
                    };

                    await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
                }
            }
            if (toAdd === "5") {
                if (res.length === 0) {
                    await collection.insertOne({
                        id: UserID,
                        FiveStar: parseInt(1)
                    })
                } else {
                    var myquery = {
                        id: UserID
                    };
                    var newvalues = {
                        $set: {
                            FiveStar: parseInt(res[0].FiveStar) + parseInt(1)
                        }
                    };

                    await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
                }
            }

        } catch (err) {
            return err;
        } finally {
            mclient.close();
        }
    },
```

My thought is - I've tried adding them as (Number(toAdd) instead of parseInt's - but its basically no matter what i do, if there is a pre-existing value in the database; the new ones will return NaN .. Instead of the actual value its supposed to.

**Any tips or ideas how to counter this would be much appreciated.**

I'm more or less half fresh to Mongo, but after searching the internet - i have no idea how to wrap my head around this issue.

Comment: You might wanna check out the `$inc` operator for mongo, which works as a +, rather than setting the value each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your response is checking for a user object and you DON'T check for the individual values again, let me demonstrate (I'll use the fail-case right away):

```js
var res = await collection.find({ id: UserID }).toArray() //res is now an Array [userObj]

if (res.length === 0) { //false since there's something in the array
        await collection.insertOne({
            id: UserID,
            OneStar: parseInt(1)
        })
    } else { //entering else now
        var myquery = {
            id: UserID
        };
        var newvalues = {
            $set: {
                OneStar: parseInt(res[0].OneStar) //now trying to parse OneStar, this however is undefined => parseInt(undefined) results in NaN
            }
        };

        await collection.updateOne(myquery, newvalues)
    }
```

You are not checking the existing amounts of ratings. You got two options on how to fix this: Either set all Ratings to 0 when creating the user object or adding a check for undefined (also use the `$inc` operator in mongo rather than settinge every time). I'll demonstrate you the undefined check:

```js
var newVals;
if(res[0].OneStar){
    newVals = { $inc: { OneStar: 1} }; //increase by one if already existing
} else {
    newVals = { $set: { OneStar: 1} }; //set to one if non-existing
}
```

Besides this, your code can be optimized by a lot since most of it looks very similiar except for the OneStar/TwoStar etc part. You could save them as strings and use the bracket syntax to access a property like

```js
let star = "OneStar";
res[0][star] ... //same as res[0].OneStar
```

but that's only a side note, I hope you understood everything

Comment: Thank you alot for the help - its definately very much appreciated!

So reading it through, i very much thank you for clearing up some stuff.

I've tried to fiddle around with the ideas - but i think i still am on the wrong path. I've added a little snippet. I 've tried adding some console logs around, but it doesn't seem like the code actualy goes inside the res[0][star] bit. (I did try (res[0].OneStar) instead )

[New code snippet](http://codebin.herokuapp.com?s=5f480330dcd9410004000014)

What could be the reason for this? I think i am looking myself completely blind on the subject

Comment: Think i got it fixed - i went ahead and added all the OneStar, TwoStar, ThreeStar by deafult upon creation in the DB & just decide to use $inc to increase them from 0 > onwards.

It seems to be working as i expected it to do now, thank you so much for the guidelines!

Comment: No problem! That's what this site is for!